# BEFORE DELETE trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

How to stop from deleting a row, that has PK in another table (without FK) with a trigger?
Is CALL cannot_delete_error  would stop from deleting?
This is what I've got so far.

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1 
BEFORE DELETE ON Clients 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT Client, Ref FROM Clients K, Invoice F
    IF F.Client = K.Ref
     CALL cannot_delete_error 
END IF;
END
```

Comment: `SELECT Client, Ref FROM Clients K, Invoice F` does not look right.

Comment: What is the exact version of MySQL you're using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `'INSTEAD OF DELETE'` trigger.

Basically, you can evaluate whether or not you should the delete the item.  In the trigger you can ultimately decide to delete the item like:

```
--test to see if you actually should delete it.


--if you do decide to delete it
DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM deleted)
```

One side note, remember that the 'deleted' table may be for several rows.

Another side note, try to do this outside of the db if possible! Or with a preceding query.  Triggers are downright difficult to maintain.  A simple query, or function (e.g. dbo.udf_CanIDeleteThis()') can be much more versatile.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL 5.5 or up you can use [`SIGNAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tg_fk_check
BEFORE DELETE ON clients
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  IF EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM invoices
             WHERE client_id = OLD.client_id) THEN
    SIGNAL sqlstate '45000' 
      SET message_text = 'Cannot delete a parent row: child rows exist';
  END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb26d)** demo. *Uncomment the last delete and click `Build Schema` to see it in action.*